# How to push props to a new page on button click?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-router, reactjs

I currently have a table and each cell has a button. Upon clicking the button, based on that particular day (Monday or Tuesday), class (class 1 or class 2), and name (Kev or Josh), how can I push an object related to that particular button in the table to a new page? Using, ReactJS + React Router + Redux, what would be the correct approach to this?

And when once navigated to the new page, the new page would then populate a table with the class information from the object passed in, related to button cell clicked.

Code:

http://jsfiddle.net/k7wbzc4j/16/

```
<table className="test-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>List</th>
      <th colSpan="2">Monday</th>
      <th colSpan="2">Tuesday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Names</th>
      <th>Class 1</th><th>Class 2</th>
      <th>Class 1</th><th>Class 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Kev</td>
      <td><button>abc</button></td><td><button>def</button></td>
      <td><button>ghi</button></td><td><button>jkl</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Josh</td>
      <td><button>mno</button></td><td><button>pqr</button></td>
      <td><button>stu</button></td><td><button>vwx</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Will accept and upvote answer. Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

Should the table rows data be structured like so and reference the object based on ID like the following? If so how can I locate that particular id object based on the cell location (with day, name, and class number taken into account)?

```
list: [
  {
    name: Kev
      monday: {
        class1: {
          id: 0,
          classTitle: abc,
          number: class1,
          info: {
            time: 1,
            classSize: 2,
          }
        },
        class 2: {
          id: 1,
          classTitle: def,
          number: class2,
          info: {
            time: 1,
            classSize: 2,
          }
        }
      },
      tuesday: {
        class1: {
          id: 2,
          classTitle: ghi,
          number: class1,
          info: {
            time: 1,
            classSize: 2,
          }
        },
        class 2: {
          id: 3,
          classTitle: jkl,
          number: class2,
          info: {
            time: 1,
            classSize: 2,
          }
        }
      },
  },

  {
    name: Josh, 
      monday: {
        class1: {
          id: 4,
          classTitle: mno,
          number: class1,
          info: {
            time: 1,
            classSize: 2,
          }
        },
        class2: {
          id: 5,
          classTitle: pqr,
          number: class2,
          info: {
            time: 1,
            classSize: 2,
          }
        }
      },
      tuesday: {
        class1: {
          id: 6,
          classTitle: stu,
          number: class1,
          info: {
            time: 1,
            classSize: 2,
          }
        },
        class2: {
          id: 7,
          classTitle: vwx,
          number: class2,
          info: {
            time: 1,
            classSize: 2,
          }
        }
      },
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS + React Router: How to reference a specific object to pass down as properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231723/reactjs-react-router-how-to-reference-a-specific-object-to-pass-down-as-prope)

Answer (score 3):

your JSFiddle doesn't use react-router or react-redux so nobody will be able to point to one particular place of your code and tell you what exactly to do differently.

that said, one typical way to do this is to use regular links (or react-router [Links](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#link)) inside your table instead of Buttons, where each link includes an `id` parameter:

`/newpage/<id>`

.  You then declare a react-router route which maps route to component:

```
<Route path="newpage" component={NewPage}>
  <Route path=":classInfoId" component={NewPage} />
</Route>
```

.  When the user visits, for example, `/newpage/123` in your app then the `NewPage` component will be rendered.  React-router will inject a `params` prop that looks like:

`{classInfoId: 123}`

.  You then fetch from your Redux store the class info object with an id of `123`, and display it as you wish.

Comment: If you can, could you show a very shallow example of your suggestion -- especially with reducer as to how an object for a button should be stored and how would the component recognize which button has been clicked, and find an object for that particular button? Would really help to clarify. So for example, each button should  have its own id?

Comment: Please take a look at the original post. Is that how the data should be structured?

Comment: Checking in to see if received my previous comment. Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Use redux reducers and actions.

On click event, reduce your state to store id or classTitle. I guess you are rendering the table dynamically with the data you have.

```
onClick = (id) => () => {
  this.props.setCurrentCell(id) // setCurrentCell is your action
  this.props.push('/new-page') // push is react-router-redux action. These actions are mapped into props with mapDispatchToProps
}

// td rendering
<td><button onClick={this.onClick(cell.id)}>{cell.classTitle}<td>
```

Create action for setCurrentCell to store current cell id, and inject that with mapStatesToProps into the new table.

Comment: Appreciate the response. Where is cell.id retrieved from and how would the component pull down the props based on its own specific id? And how should the data be structured? A sample of mine is in the original post.

Comment: @JoKo The `cell.id` i mean is the id of your data leaf. Current data structure looks fine. But you will want to render table `td`s by mapping array into react components, rather than render them manually.

Comment: Do you mind showing an example along with the code provided for clarification?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly... I'd suggest you look into the 'push' action that is part of react-router-redux.

link: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux

Do a search for 'push' and look for the example where they showcase it being used as below:

store.dispatch(push('/foo'))

What they are doing there is directing the user from their existing page to the next page '/foo' without losing their state.

Because your state is maintained, once you are on your next page, you can peek into your Redux store and all of your store data should still be there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @sean Thank you for the response. How would the component know which id props to pull down, and how would the component pull down the props based on its own specific id? And any suggestions on how should the data be structured? A sample of mine is in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You should create the dispatcher to store the object into redux state container before redirecting to next page.

Below is the code snippet.

```
<Button disabled={!this.state.selectedParent} onClick={this.goNextPage} />

goNextPage() {
    const {dispatch} = this.props;
    dispatch(saveSelectedOrganization({
        parentNode:this.state.selectedParent,
        organizationData: this.props.list
    }));

    browserHistory.push('/admin/orgatnizations/create');
}
```

Comment: but how would this work for a page dedicated to a specific button?